# How to edit the CashAccount attribute globally

Tags: acumatica

I need to add two inner joins and a Where clause to any search that is used on a CashAccount attribute.  I want to make this change globally so that all fields that have the CashAccount attribute are limited by the Where clause that I want to add.  I'm trying to avoid having to hunt down every field that has the CashAccount attribute and either change the Search<> that it's using or replace the CashAccount attribute with a custom one.  Is it possible?

For instance, on this constructor for the CashAccount attribute, I want to add 2 Inner Joins and a Where to the "search" parameter that is passed in to the constructor.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of the new CashAccountAttribute object. Filter by branch, doesn't suppress <see cref="CashAccount.Active"/> status verification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="branchID">Identifier for the branch.</param>
    /// <param name="search">The type of search. Should implement <see cref="IBqlSearch"/> or <see cref="IBqlSelect"/></param>
    public CashAccountAttribute(Type branchID, Type search) : base(branchID, search)
    {
    }
```

I've tried overriding the CacheAttached event in order to append two joins to the search that is passed into my custom attribute but, this is giving an error on Cash Sale screen when I select the Customer for the Cash Sale.  I made this change on the Cash Sale screen only.  I replaced the CashAccount attribute and replaced it with a custom attribute that inherits the CashAccount attribute.

```
    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        base.CacheAttached(sender);

        BqlCommand oldbql = this.SelectorAttribute.GetSelect();
        BqlCommand newbql = BqlCommand.AppendJoin(oldbql, typeof(InnerJoin<Branch, On<Branch.branchID, Equal<Current<CashAccount.branchID>>>>));
        newbql = BqlCommand.AppendJoin(newbql, typeof(InnerJoin<Organization, On<Organization.organizationID, Equal<Current<Branch.organizationID>>>>));
        
        this._Attributes.Remove(this.SelectorAttribute);
        PXDimensionSelectorAttribute selectorAttr = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("CASHACCOUNT",newbql.GetType());
        this._Attributes.Add(selectorAttr);

        
    }
```

Any ideas would be great.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to alter an attribute globally as well, and I think what you describe is a 2-step process as outlined **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014304/how-do-i-override-an-event-handler-inside-an-attribute)**.

First you want to create your own attribute inheriting from the original.  (I know, you said you want to replace the other attribute globally, but that's accomplished in step 2 if this method works for you as it did for me.)  Make the adjustments in your attribute so that it works when you use it directly.  This is purely for testing purposes that you use it directly.

Second, use a DAC extension or graph extensions (using cacheattached) to use YOUR attribute.  If the DAC is extended to replace it, then everywhere the DAC is used should be impacted.  If the attribute is used within graphs, this may mean adding graph extensions for each one to use cacheattached to do the same thing within those graphs.

Please note that you will need to remove the original attribute with

```
[PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(CashAccountAttribute))]
```

and then add your new attribute.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I'm still lost on how to modify the "Type search" parameter on the constructor in order to add my inner joins and where.  I tried putting some code in the constructor of my custom attribute class but, it's never ran.